# Update whole class in Realm Swift in 1 time wont work

Tags: swift, realm

Imagine this code:

```
class StoredVersions: Object{
    @objc dynamic var minimumAppVersion = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var sets = 0.0
}
class LoadViewController: UIViewController { 
    let realm = try! Realm()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var newestVersions = StoredVersions()
    if let resultsStoredVersion = self.realm.objects(StoredVersions.self).first{
        print("found stored versions: \(resultsStoredVersion)")
        self.storedVersions = resultsStoredVersion
    }else{
        try! self.realm.write {
            print("no stored versions")
            self.realm.add(self.storedVersions)
        }
    }

    db.collection("data").document("version").getDocument(completion: { (data, someError) in
            if let versions = data.flatMap({StoredVersions(value: $0.data()) }) {
               try! self.realm.write {
                    self.storedVersions = versions
                }
            }
        })
}
```

storedVersions is updated but when I restart the application, storedVersions is back to its initial state. I do see the print "found stored versions".

If I write just 1 variable at a time, it works. That looks like this:

```
   try! self.realm.write {
      self.storedVersions.sets = versions.sets
    }
```

How can I update a whole class without having to put in variables one at a time?

Comment: Can you share a little more context, please? For instance, the class definition of the class with the `storedVersions` property, the input you're providing (i.e., `data`), and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: hi @bdash, I edited my question to add some more context, I can add more if you want. The input I am providing and my expected result is the "should be" print (a print of "versions"). My "storedVersions" should contain the same values as "versions".

Comment: Can you please share the class declaration that contains the code being executed?

Comment: @bdash I added the UIViewController code now. storedVersions removes itself at the restart of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
if let versions = data.flatMap({StoredVersions(value: $0.data()) }) {
    try! self.realm.write {
        self.storedVersions = versions
    }
}
```

You're creating a new, unmanaged `StoredVersions` object. You need to call `realm.add(_:)` to add it to the Realm, otherwise the object only exists in memory.

If you want to *update* the existing `StoredVersions` object rather than creating a new one, you should instead use `Realm.add(_:update:)`, specifying `true` for the update argument. Note that this requires your type have a primary key property declared so that Realm knows which existing object to update.

Comment: Thank you it works. But I think it is very strange that updating 1 variable works the way I want, but when updating a whole class requires more hassle with keys and updates.

Comment: When you're modifying properties of `self.storedVersions`, you're modifying the properties of an object that's _already_ managed by Realm (you just retrieved it from the Realm, after all). That's completely different than creating a new, _unmanaged_ object.

Comment: Ha! Now I get it finally! Thanks for your time.